# Creating new Records in FLOW

Tags: visual-workflow, create-records

So I'm new to using flow and i'm doing something wrong. Hoping someone could help to get me on the correct path.

I have a very simply flow that I'm trying to do that involves pulling a record collection from the Subscription object and creating a new record for each record in the collection in a custom object called Entitlements using only 4 of the data points.

My preference is to have the bulk create work and not have to loop through, but I cant seem to get that to work so I tried looping through and creating the records within the loop, but that does not seem to work either.

Here is what is currently setup with the loop. When I run, I do not get an error, but the records are not being created. The fields I'm trying to include are:

- Account ID (Destination field is Lookup)
- Contract Number (Destination field is Text)
- Product Name (Destination field is Text)
- Product ID (Destination field is Text)

Any help is massively appreciated

[image]

Comment: Ahhh I got the loop working. It was a simple mistake of assigning the incorrect Record collection.

Comment: You want to avoid creating records in a loop.  In the loop use a second assignment to add the variable to a collection, and then once the loop finishes use a create records element to insert the full collection in one step.  This will bulkify better.

Comment: Paste your debug log here, please. What does it say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid creating records inside a loop. It might fail if there are too many records. Also, it's not the best practice.

You can create a record variable of type 'Entitlement', assign the field's values for Entitlement record inside the loop, and add this variable to the Entitlement record collection variable.

Use a single 'Create Records' element after the loop and insert the Entitlement record collection variable.

**Edit**

Adding an example:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you add add the record variable to a collection? This is the part I'm struggling with. I'm guessing a second assignment where I set the the Variable as the Collection, Operator as Add, and the value as the Record.field?

Comment: Yes. I have added an example for your reference.

Comment: You are the man. This helped. My flow is now working. No more creating within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we want to avoid the pink inside the loop as much as possible.

1. Create a record variable: *Subscription*.
2. Create a collection variable: *Subscriptions*.
3. In a *Loop*, use an Assignment element to assign values to fields in the *Subscription* record variable.
4. Make the *Id* field blank if you intend to use *Create Records*. For *Update Records*, of course, *Id* needs to be populated.
5. At the end of the Assignment as the last step: *Subscriptions>Add>Subscription*.
6. After the end of the loop, use a Create or Update with the *Multiple* option and *Subscriptions* as the collection.

An example below shows my Configuration Component (CC) Records being generated and added to a collection in this way.

I just want to comment for others' benefit that I had an older flow that ran API version 52, and the above steps did not work properly because the fields did not get properly assigned when I had the *Collection>Add>Record* in the same Assignment element as the field assignments. Changing it to version 57 fixed that. This is my main reason for writing this answer. Hope it helps someone.

[image: An example from one of my flows]

[image: Assignment Element]